# MySQL get value and sum them up

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to sum up all the values in this script below but not sure how to do it, I searched the net and found array_sum() but not sure where to use it...

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $a = $row['aa'];
  $b = $row['bb'];
  $c = $row['cc'];
  }
```

in the script above, all the variables has a value of either 1 or 0, I can manually add them by using $a + $b + $c but if the list gets longer it will take some time. Is there a faster way so that i can add up everything?

illustration of table

```
  ID   NAME   AA   BB   CC
  1    YOU    1    0    1
  2    ME     1    1    1
```

So what i want is that "YOU" will have the value of 2 while "ME" will have the value of 3

Comment: Yes, use MySQL's `SUM()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT (aa+bb+cc) AS yoursum FROM yourtable
```

According to your comment, I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(aa), SUM(bb), SUM(cc) AS yoursum FROM yourtable
```

Or this, if there name column can have duplicates.

```
SELECT name, SUM(aa+bb+cc) AS yoursum 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, but from w3schools the definition is SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name (so i was a little confused). I've updated my question.

Comment: Then you need the first query. If there are many rows with `Name=Me` then you need the third query.

Comment: @Crays: Try all answers and you'll see that you need the `SELECT (aa+bb+cc) AS yoursum FROM yourtable` one.

Comment: You can also have both columns and their sum: `SELECT ID, name, (aa+bb+cc) AS yoursum, aa, bb, cc AS yoursum FROM yourtable`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

A slightly modified version of @cularis solution (in case you want only one value in the end):

```
SELECT (SUM(aa) + SUM(bb) + SUM(cc)) AS yoursum FROM yourtable
```

I myself would probably use one of the aggregate functions build into MySQL (most likely the SUM()). You can read more of these functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I think he wants to calculate values of the same  row?

Comment: Ah... then my solution is wrong. Sorry for the confusion caused in that case. Nevertheless I can't help noticing that there is a while loop in the given code example where multiple rows are fetched (probably to an associative array), hence, I thought the thread owner requested multi-row aggregation.

Comment: If not mistaken, sum() only calculate by columns right? What if mine is by rows? Which means i have something like this

ID NAME AA BB CC

Comment: @Crays sum() calculates over rows. Please be more specific and update your question to reflect what you want.